# harfbuzz downgrade issues

Tags: apt, kali-linux, dependencies

My system crashed due to a `harfbuzz` related incompatibility. So I tried to downgrade the `harfbuzz` packages to version `2.7.4-1`, and I got a strange result! More than 500 packages will be deleted with the downgrade and I don't want that. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a solution?

Simply don't downgrade a very common dependency. The whole point of using a linux distro is that it provides coordinated dependencies, i.e., the programs you can install depend exactly on the version of a library supplied by the system.

Instead of trying to use a different version of a library than your system supplies, build the software you need against the version of harfbuzz that your kali has.

This is a no-brainer, anyways, since you're using Kali, which is not in any way a platform you'd ever run closed-source software that you can't compile yourself, on.